# Calculate width for text in TextSpan

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a TextSpan (see code below). I want to calculate the width of the text so I can align my text in the center.

How do I do that ?

```
final textSpan = TextSpan(
    text: ' $title ',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: titleColor,
      fontSize: fontSize,
      height: 1.0,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    final textSpan = TextSpan(
      text: ' $title ',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: titleColor,
        fontSize: fontSize,
        height: 1.0,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      ),
    );
    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: textSpan)
      ..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: double.infinity);
    print(textPainter.size); //the TextSpan width
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate size of any text you can use this function:

```
Size measure(String text, TextStyle style,
      {int maxLines: 1, TextDirection direction = TextDirection.ltr, double maxWidth = double.infinity}) {
    final TextPainter textPainter =
        TextPainter(text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style), maxLines: maxLines, textDirection: direction)
          ..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: maxWidth);
    return textPainter.size;
  }
```

as you can see - you have to pass text and textsyle, optionally maxlines, text direction and width constraint.